# Adding java time objects

Tags: java, datetime, time

How do you say, add 1 hour to a given result from calendar.getTime?

Comment: trying to figure out why this got down-voted...

Comment: probably because its a one liner.. it wasn't exactly a complex question though. just new to java. Oh some people *do* suck, I think that could be it.

Comment: Actually, it's a remarkably complex question when you get into DST changes. Do you always expect 01:30 + 1 hour to be 02:30, for instance?

Comment: It's a one liner *and* it's not terribly clear. `getTime` gives you a `Date`; is that what you really want to modify?

Comment: +1 to undo the downvote. Stack Overflow is supposed to be a place where people can ask legitimate questions and not be made to feel stupid about them. I don't think downvoting simple questions or answering them with "have you tried Googling for the answer?" is necessarily appropriate on SO.

Comment: Thankyou grant. Also, Jon, I don't think it is much of a complex question, but it sure is a complex answer. I have a server in new zealand and a server in the US that both require time expiring authentications. One other problem is the US box needs to talk to another US server which happens to be in a different time zone. :(

Comment: ps of course I tried to google the answer.. its one of those questions that just give very varied and broken search results. Especially when you need to get into timezone differences. Its the type of question SO was built to solve.

Comment: @jim: For this sort of thing, I wouldn't use a calendar at all. Just use the UTC time everywhere - you don't even need to use a human-readable format for it most of the time, just use the number of milliseconds since the epoch. Then you can just add the number of milliseconds you want. Only format it to a human-readable form when you need to display it to someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.now().plusHours( 1 )
```

…or…

```
ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal"  ).plusHours( 1 )
```

## Using java.time

The accepted Answer is correct but outdated.

The troublesome old legacy date-time classes have been supplanted by the java.time classes.

Instead of `Calendar`, use `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
ZonedDateTime zdtOneHourLater = zdt.plusHours( 1 );
```

Note that the [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) may not be an hour later. Anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) means an hour later may appear to be *two* hours later jumping from 1 AM to 3 AM for DST switch-over.

For converting from old `Calendar` to modern java.time types, see [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36639154/642706).

Most of your work should be in UTC. For that, use the `Instant` class.

```
Instant hourLater = Instant.now().plusHours( 1 );
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.

Answer (score 7):

Well, you can add 1000 * 60 * 60 to the millisecond value of the `Date`. That's probably the simplest way, if you don't want to mutate the `Calendar` instance itself. (I wouldn't like to guess exactly what `Calendar` will do around DST changes, by the way. It may well not be adding an hour of UTC time, if you see what I mean.)

So if you *do* want to go with the Date approach:

```
date.setTime(date.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60);
```

This will *always* add an actual hour, regardless of time zones, because a `Date` instance doesn't have a time zone - it's just a wrapper around a number of milliseconds since midnight on Jan 1st 1970 UTC.

However, I'd strongly advise (as I always do with Java date/time questions) that you use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) instead. It makes this and myriad other tasks a *lot* easier and more reliable. I know I sound like a broken record on this front, but the very fact that it forces you to think about whether you're *actually* talking about a local date/time, just a date, a local midnight etc makes a big difference.

Comment: +1 for DST - incredibly easy to miss, next to impossible to reproduce and fix when it blows up in production 4 months later.

 BTW, this is the 2nd question I'm seeing today where Jon's answer is not the top one. Is the world as we know it coming to an abrupt end? :-)

Comment: as in depth and as helpful as your answer was, rich needs some noobie love and his answer really was exactly what I needed. Something I should have grabbed from the javadocs but missed :)

Answer (score 4):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
//cal.setTime(date); //if you need to pass in a date
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
```